# Info button vanishes from view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I have a view xib that contains an info button. I'm doing animation on the UIView by adding CALayer objects to the view's layer and animating these layers. I'm careful to place these layers behind the info button by moving their zPosition. The problem is that on a real iPod touch the info button does not show in the view, even though it's area is responding fine to touches. Note that the same button shows fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the info button layer from its super layer, then adding my own layers used for animation and finally adding back the info button layer. This does keep the  info button layer properly displayed.